# C socket read outputs empty string when using one line telnet statement

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

I have a problem reading a client input through a TCP socket using telnet and echo in one line. It only works when i input the message in a 'normal' telnet session:

**Client Console**

```
devbox cehrig # telnet 127.0.0.1 50231
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Test Message
Connection closed by foreign host.
devbox cehrig # echo "One Liner" | telnet 127.0.0.1 50231
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
devbox cehrig #
```

**Server Console**

```
Mon Apr  6 16:36:41 2015: Accepting connections...
Mon Apr  6 16:36:45 2015: Inbound connection from  127.0.0.1
Client msg: Test Message
Mon Apr  6 16:36:48 2015: Accepting connections...
Mon Apr  6 16:44:06 2015: Inbound connection from  127.0.0.1
Client msg: 
Mon Apr  6 16:44:06 2015: Accepting connections...
```

"Client msg" keeps being empty when trying to send data with echo "" | telnet ....

This is the function I'm using to read from the client socket:

```
void read_socket(int idntef, 
         config_t * cfg)
{
    int n;
    char * _buf = (char *) malloc(512*sizeof(char));
    char * _cor = (char *) malloc(512*sizeof(char));
    char * _out = _cor;

    bzero(_buf, 512);
    bzero(_cor, 512);


    if((n = read(idntef, _buf, 511)) < 0) {
        _print(stderr, "messages.socketreadfail", cfg, 1);
        _exit(0);
    }

    int x = 0;
    while(*_buf != '\n' && x++ <= 512) {
        *_cor++ = *_buf++;
    }

    printf("Client msg: %s\n", _out);
    fflush(stdout);
    shutdown(idntef, 2);
}
```

Does sbd has a hint for me, what to improve here?

Comment: `while(*_buf != '\n' && x++ <= 512) {` is wrong. Alo you should test against the `n` variable. Plus: there is no need to read only 511 bytes into a 512 size buffer ( `if((n = read(idntef, _buf, 511)) < 0) {` )

Comment: On my Mac (running OS X 10.10.2), at least, the echo | telnet trick doesn't work; it causes telnet to connect and then immediately disconnect without sending any characters.

Comment: telnet is a protocol, it needs to connect to a telnet process. (there is a bunch of handshaking to be performed)  a standalone 'read()' will not properly setup a telnet connection.

Comment: This is a telnet 'issue', descriped here: stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts @JeremyFriesner this worked for me: { echo "Test"; sleep 1; } | telnet <IP> <Port>

Comment: @user3629249 nevertheless it is possible to use a telnet client to troubleshoot (non-telnet) ASCII-based TCP protocols, if the program under test doesn't mind seeing the occasional telnet command character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee data will be sent in one block. You need to read in a loop until '\n' is found or buffer limit reached.

Something like:

```
size_t size=0;
do {
    if((n = read(idntef, _buf+size, 512-size)) < 0) {
        _print(stderr, "messages.socketreadfail", cfg, 1);
        _exit(0);
    }
    size += n;
} while(strchr(_buf, '\n') == NULL && size < 512);
```